# Showing WordPress plugin settings in jQuery UI tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am currently developing a WordPress plugin using the [WordPress Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_API%27s) to create an option page. So I am using `register_setting`, `add_settings_field`, `settings_fields` and `do_settings_sections` to create the HTML code.

This all works fine.

However I need to device the settings in various tabs of a jQuery UI tab interface.

Currently I am using the callback function within `add_settings_field` to generate the HTML for the specific element, but each element now has to be assigned to a specific tab sheet.

I am aware that WordPress API has tabs built in also, but these require me to save settings before I change between them and this is not what I am currently looking for.

Comment: do you want to make your own settings page for your plugin or do you want to hook into one of wordpress' pages?

Comment: If you are asking me if I create my own file, e.g. my_plugin_settings.php then no. I am using WordPress Settings API (http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) to create me the option/setting page.

Comment: if I were you, i'd forget about settings api and put my whole markup for the settings page (tabs,forms, etc) and the request handling (with saving of the options using update_option() calls) in the admin page callback function. you'd have total control in this case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by creating my own version of do_settings_sections and settings_fields based upon the WordPress one. Within these custom functions (only available for the plugin it self) I am adjusting the HTML that is rendered so the DIV elements required for jQuery are put on the right places.